# From array to 2D array devided by 2 values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an array:

```
arr =["112000666", "10", "111282637", "15", "111342625", "12", "112000674",
      "11", "111488203", "18", "111237150", "20"]
```

Is there any way to make a 2D array and divided by 2 values? Something like this:

```
[["112000666", "10"], ["111282637", "15"], ["111342625", "12"],
 ["112000674", "11"], ["111488203", "18"], ["111237150", "20"]]
```

The number of elements will always be even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For rails** you can use [in_groups_of](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) method:

```
arr.in_groups_of(2)
  #=> [["112000666", "10"], ["111282637", "15"], ["111342625", "12"],
  #    ["112000674", "11"], ["111488203", "18"], ["111237150", "20"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! You are my savior!

Answer (score 4):

Pure Ruby:

```
arr.each_slice(2).to_a
  #=> [["112000666", "10"], ["111282637", "15"], ["111342625", "12"],
  #    ["112000674", "11"], ["111488203", "18"], ["111237150", "20"]]
```

See [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).